# How to set alias for localhost for Springboot app with specific port?

Tags: spring-boot, localhost, alias, hostname

I created two Springboot web applications (with Tomcat embedded) and I am able to run them on my local machine, one on 8080 port, second on 8085 port.

I am able to access them both locally at http://localhost:8080 and http://localhost:8085 .

I would like to change the localhost name to different hostnames, for example:

- http://localhost:8080 -> http://first-application/
- http://localhost:8085 -> http://second-application/

I added into hosts file:

- 127.0.0.1:8080 first-application
- 127.0.0.1:8085 second-application

However I am still not able to access my applications on localhost on http://first-application/ and http://second-application/ .

How can I achieve that? Thanks for answers.

Comment: As far as I know, hosts file is for mapping host names and/or IP addresses, nothing related with ports. I would put something in port 80 (may be an Apache HTTP Server with reverse proxy rules) that depending on the hostname sends the traffic to the appropriate port (application).

Comment: You have to manage this like how Docker or Kubernates does. Meaning, you can deploy in Docker and can configure like http://your-domain.com I don't think you can do this using embedded servers.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Michal an alternative is to configure nginx as a reverse proxy...
https://developpaper.com/deploying-spring-boot-application-with-nginx-reverse-proxy/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).